# What is this leaf vegetable? It tastes like cress but looks different

Tags: vegetables, food-identification

My girlfriend got this at a Turkish supermarket in Berlin. It's quite spicy and tastes like garden cress or a bit like radish. I looked up cress varieties but couldn't find this particular leaf shape.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a variety of watercress to me.

Comment: You're probably right, I was misled by some pictures which looked different. A picture search for watercress shows that some variants look almost exactly like this.

Comment: Gardening might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @GdD.  I agree it looks like watercress to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have Baby Argula or Rocket.  Check out this site for Turkish greens.
http://www.turkish-cuisine.org/ingredients-7/ingredients-used-in-turkish-cuisine-66/vegetables-69.html

Answer (score -4):

This is coriander, watercress grows on a longer stalk.

Comment: The taste of coriander doesn't match the poster's description. Besides, this looks more like radish than coriander to me.

Comment: Definitely not coriander/cilantro. The leaves are not at all the right shape (they're oval and not lobed), and they're not branching off of long stems.

Comment: Agreed with the others. The shape is not remotely close to cilantro and the flavour description doesn't match, either.

Comment: There is a faint similarity to vietnamese and/or sawtooth coriander, but still different - and FAR from "cilantro" coriander.